# remove an object from an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove an object from an Array by id for example:

```
users = [{id: "10051", name: "Mike Coder"},{id: "4567", name: "Jhon Second"}]
```

Say I want to remove user with id "10051" using javascript, I tried searching the internet but couldn't find anything?

plus I do not want to use underscore!

Comment: You're getting answers showing how to build a new, filtered Array, but your question seems to ask how to remove it from the current Array. Which one did you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> plus I do not want to use underscore!

The native method for this is [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var removeId = "4567";
users = users.filter(function (user) { return user.id !== removeId; });
```

Note that it requires the engine be [ES5-compatible](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.filter) (or a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility)).

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i)
{
    if ( users[i].id == "10051" )
    {
        users[i].splice(i--, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.filter` method of array.

```
users = users.filter(function(el) {return el.id !== '10051'});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var users= [{id:"10051", name:"Mike Coder"},{id:"4567", name:"Jhon Second"}];

/* users.length= 2 */

function removebyProperty(prop, val, multiple){
    for(var i= 0, L= this.length;i<L;i++){
        if(i in this && this[i][prop]=== val){
            this.splice(i, 1);
            if(!multiple) i= L;
        }
    }
    return this.length;
}
```

**removebyProperty.call(users,'id',"10051");**

**returned value: (Number) 1**

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you used `this` in the function along with `.call()` instead of just receiving the Array as a parameter, eliminating the need for `.call()`.

Comment: @Pokey- well, it is a narrowly focused function that does one thing on one particular sort of object. I'm comfortable using it as a method of the object, so I call it like one.